# How to identify common queries for a topic?

Tags: google-search, search-engine, bing

I'm trying to understand the most common queries entered on Google (or Bing or Yahoo!) for a given topic, in the context of a study. This is not exactly SEO, but it's closely related.

In my study, I want to investigate what search engines return regarding (for example) the causes of the war in Iraq, and see what content is being displayed. I don't manage any site on the topic: I am interested in the **most popular queries** entered on search engines for this topic.

The problem is: as a user, I can enter a variety of queries to investigate that topic, such as:

- iraq war causes
- war in Iraq causes
- causes of the war in iraq
- war iraq democracy
- war iraq oil
- war iraq terrorism
- etc

Each query obviously returns different results - although some pages are returned for most queries.
Unsurprisingly, it seems that no big search engine like Google or Bing release precise data on popular queries around a topic.
So basically I can't assess exactly the most common queries.
To solve this issue, I could select a set of arbitrary but reasonable queries for a topic, and analyse the results, but the study would be heavily biased by my choices.

What method would you adopt to select a set of queries that represent well a given topic? I couldn't find any well-established methodology to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends).

For example, here is the trend page for the search [iraq war](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=iraq).

The bottom of the page shows similar queries and rankings.

[image: Google Trends]

At the top of the page, you can download a csv of more complete statistics (under the gear icon).